# How to cast ArrayList to SubType Of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

Class Structure

```
class Packet {}
class PacketList extends ArrayList<Packet> {}
```

---

Now I am trying to cast object of ArrayList  to Object of PacketList

```
List<Packet>  p = new ArrayList<Packet> ();
PacketList pList = p;
```

---

But it will not work. Please help me out

### **Error Message:**

incompatible types: List cannot be converted to PacketList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PacketList` extended the `ArrayList<Packet>`, which means newly introduced, or overriden methods that might require and depend on other artifacts only introduced in the new `PacketList` version. What if it refers to instance variables only available in `PacketList`? `ArrayList` won't have those instance variables, although you would intend to access them through those methods ...

No, you cannot assign an instance of a superclass, to a variable of the type matching an extending class.

You work the other way around, you use the super type as the generic type to assign extending (subclassed) instances.